# I want to add two text variables and text to a label widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a tkinter `Label` widget that I am using to display query results in a new window. I want to display 2 things in the same label depending on the query choices.

Here is my code:

```
Label(newWindow, textvariable=selected_diff + " Hikes in " + selected_park, width=50, 
      fg="black", font=("bold", 12), bd=1, relief="raised").grid(row=0, column=3)
```

I know I could just create 3 separate `Label`s, but I think it would look bad, and be hacky.

This is my callback error - I guess you cannot use + to concatinate `str` and `StringVar` in the same widget? Seems unlikely — more likely I am doing some formatting wrong.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mount\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:/PycharmProjects/SIE557_2021_FP/fp_comboboxes.py", line 289, in search_hikes
    Label(newWindow, textvariable=selected_diff + " Hikes in " + selected_park, width=50, fg="black", font=("bold", 12), bd=1, relief="raised").grid(row=0, column=3)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'StringVar' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You can only use 1 `StringVar` per `tkinter.Label`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @theLizzard I have comboboxes to choose variables for an sql database query, park name and difficulty level of hike. all that works fine. I want the label to read "difficulty name" Hikes in "park name" so i don't need to display a column of the difficulty level in the table, since they are all the same value it looks bad i think. I can make it display the park name or difficulty name, but maybe as you say I cannot display both. that's too bad, seems like a basic thing.

Comment: Do you know how to use `<Stringvar>.trace`? You can trace both variables and use `<tkinter.Label>.config(text=<new text>)` to set the new text.

Comment: @TheLizzard I am not familiar with it, but thank you I will look into it.

Comment: Display both? Can you show an expected output? Why not use `if`.

Comment: You know its really fine if you dont use tkinter variables? Like: `Label(newWindow, text=selected_diff + " Hikes in " + selected_park, ...)` where `selected_diff` and `selected_park` are variables containing your needed values.

Comment: @CoolCloud I tried that, but it didn't work. I set the selected values to str values in another variable.

Comment: As @TheLizzard suggested, you can use tkinter variable "tracing" to do what you want. See [Tracing Tkinter variables in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/) for more info. If you edited your question and provided a [mre], someone might post an answer with code in it showing how it's done…

Comment: I don't understand what you need here. Include an example of how you want it to look like and you might get some quality answers

Comment: @coolCloud It was pretty well explained. TheLizzard had not trouble understanding my question, and his answer was very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I don't see why you need `trace` here. You said you tried `text` instead of `textvariable` and it didn't work. Why? And if you already got your answer why not post it already or delete the question too? At the top you can see that even @TheLizzard asks for extra clarification :D